# Why .cshtml file don't see @model in .cshtml.cs file and i get Null References exception?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, nullreferenceexception

I've created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, and I want to see "Test" when i request it but I'm getting `NullReferenceException`. But when I create the Razor pages application and try the same thing on that project, I don't get any errors.

I run app on Ubuntu 22.04, I use .NET Core 6.0 Framework.

```
namespace MyApp.Namespace
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        public string? Message { get; set; }
        
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyApp.Namespace.TestModel

<dir>@Model.Message</dir>
```

Exception:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Home_Test.ExecuteAsync() in Test.cshtml
>
> @Model.Message

I tried to change namespaces and add a `@page` directive in Razor page. Nothing has changed.

Comment: MVC != Razor Pages In MVC you return to the View passing the model

Comment: i return View() in HomeController . I understand that I cannot use the model in Tetst.cshtml.cs in mvc structure. I have to use ViewBags. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code above you should make the following declaration in the Razor view file:

```
@page
@using MyApp.Namespace
@model TestModel 

<dir>@Model.Message</dir>
```

Detailed instructions on how to create a Razor Pages and `@page`, `@model` declarations  you can find in the Microsoft documentation here: [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages)

Answer (score 0):

MVC needs to pass model between View and controller. When you want to show values from backend, you need to return view with models.

**create a model to pass data:**

```
 public class TestModel
    {
        public string? Message { get; set; }
    }
```

**set the default value in http get action:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            TestModel test = new TestModel();
            test.Message = "Test";

            //return view with model
            return View(test);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model TestModel

<h1>@Model.Message</h1>
```

**Now you can show `Test` in your view:**

[image]